# Why my Sublime Text 3 packages not working?

Tags: package, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I have installed several packages. But suddenly things stopped working.

Even package control itself. Also several preferences menu items are greyed out. There is nothing in ingnore_packages array.

Here what I do, may be cause of this.

- I synced with dropbox and then deleted dropbox.
- Download some heavy packages.

here my console;

```
DPI mode: per-monitor v2
startup, version: 3176 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/Mehmet/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/Mehmet/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/Mehmet/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: []
Errors parsing theme:
icon_file_type is missing layer0.opacity, setting to 1.0 for backwards compatibility
pre session restore time: 0.608607
startup time: 0.666607
first paint time: 0.668607
reloading plugin Default.arithmetic
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.colors
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_color_scheme
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.install_package_control
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.rename
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.settings
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin Default.ui
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin ShellScript.ShellScript
reloading plugin Vintage.vintage
reloading plugin Vintage.vintage_commands
reloading plugin Vintage.vintage_motions
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.01-pygments
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-markupsafe
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-pymdownx
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-python-markdown
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-pyyaml
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.51-python-jinja2
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.55-jsonschema
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.55-mdpopups
reloading plugin A File Icon.A File Icon
reloading plugin AdvancedNewFile.AdvancedNewFile
reloading plugin Colorsublime.colorsublime-plugin
reloading plugin Material Theme.Icons
reloading plugin Material Theme.MT
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin PHP Companion.PHP Companion
reloading plugin PHP CS Fixer.SublimePhpCsFixer
reloading plugin phpunitkit.plugin
reloading plugin ProjectManager.json_file
reloading plugin ProjectManager.project_manager
reloading plugin SnippetMaker.SnippetMaker
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-phpcs.linter
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.__init__
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.active_linters_view
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.busy_indicator_view
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.goto_commands
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.highlight_view
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.log_handler
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.message_view
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.panel_view
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.status_bar_view
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.sublime_linter
reloading plugin CodeComplice.CodeComplice
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.ordereddict
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.SublimeCodeIntel
thread finalize
```

How could I go about this?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat . My english is not much good. It can cause this. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, Got it. The Sublimecodeintel cause this. just remove from packages and problem solved.